# rails flash graph/chart plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graph, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am looking for a rails flash graph/chart plugin, for drawing 
bar chart,
stacked bar chart,
pie chart,
stacked area chart,
and line graphs

which support the below criteria,
1. Customizable tool tip. For eg: when i am drawing a stacked area graph, i want to display all the y axix values for that x axis point as tool tip.
2. Graph should support on click event
3. The graph should be able to send as an image through inline attachment.
4. Column graph, that should be able to display the value above the bar.
5. Should be able to turn off the animation
6. We can draw two y axis

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Nithy"

EDIT: I am willing to purchase a commercial license if its servers the purpose.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know which ones will have all the features that you want but I was playing with charts a while ago and this is a list of some possibilities:

1. Ziya(http://ziya.liquidrail.com/) - Rails plugin
2. AmCharts (http://www.amcharts.com/) - The one I ended up using because of flexibility - No rails plugin but it is quite simple to deploy using with rails XML support (I guess it does export images and has all the features you want though it might take a little while to understand and make full use of it)
3. Fusion Charts (http://www.fusioncharts.com/) - Seems to be a good option if you are willing to inve$t some money on it
4. Gruff (http://nubyonrails.com/pages/gruff) - Also rails plugin - I don't remember anymore why I decided against it but I think it was because of the lack of animation
5. OpenFlash (http://openflashchart.com/) - I liked this one though I just used as a proof of concept

I also did try the Timeplot (http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeplot/) that is totally javascript because I had a problem with the amount of points it was required for my charts and the flash-based solutions had several limitations on that. Though I gave it up because of deployment time contraints.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Highcharts http://www.highcharts.com/

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I also heavily use AmCharts in conjonction with the [Ambling](http://github.com/ahobson/ambling/tree/master) Rails plugin.

If you go this way, know that you will pass time in the AmCharts reference documentation for fine-tuning the parameters of your charts. But it's worthwhile considering the results it give.